# Masks: Setting "MaskValues" parameter failling on matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab, simulink, mask

I am currently working with a bunch of code using matlab programatically controlled masks.

I just ran into a new problem, which I did not experience before.

I have to change a checkbox state in the mask, I am basically doing the following:

```
maskNames = get_param(gcb, 'MaskNames');
maskValues = get_param(gcb, 'MaskValues');

// search in maskNames for the checkbox 
// change the corresponding index in maskValues (from "on" to "off" in this case)

set_param(gcb, 'MaskValues', maskValues);
```

For some reason, this is not working under matlab 2014b. The checkbox remains checked, and if I perform a *"get_param('MaskValues')"* I can see the value is still to "on".

This works on Matlab2011b (same code, no version branches).

However, if I do a simple : *set_param(gcb, 'ParameterName', 'off'*), then it works. However I cannot really do this as there could be multiple checkbox to change at once and we are using the MaskNames cell search in order to determine which mask component should be modified.

What I do not get, is that I already work on masked blocks and **we are using the exact same framework to communicate with them**. So basically on other blocks on which I am setting popups, it is working on matlab 2014b.

So I'd like to have an insight of what could cause this problem and how to solve it, because basically I am in a situation where I cannot guarantee that the other chunks of code and other existing blocks using this technique will continue to work or are not even already broken.

Thank you guys

Comment: Try the same code from command line and see if it works. Also try manually getting maskvalues and toggling one checkbox from command line and see if it works. May be there are new mask parameters affecting your index calculation.

Comment: We did this check. First, it's work. Then if you use the GUI, it won't. But you can still make the state change using classical set_param

Comment: You can try putting the entire code in an external function and then see from debugger whether the function is called from mask and that it runs correctly. Is it the same block that worked previously or for a different block?